# ascending or descending order according to boolean column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

This is the table structure in PostgreSQL 10.
[image]

Even though "date" is an `int`, it represents a yyyy mm dd date. I am trying to write a `SELECT` that orders by date and when it is BC=true it is `desc`, so dates will be in the right order -500 01 02 then -500 01 03 (yyyy mm dd) 
and when is is BC=false it is `asc`, so dates will be in the right order again 1500 01 02, then 150 01 03 (yyyy mm dd)

I came up with this `SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY bc=true desc, bc=false asc;` that does great on BC dates, but it flips the AD dates (15000103 then 15000102, that is wrong).

I know there is the `date` type available, but I want this to work as a hack for exact BC dates.

How can I change my `SELECT` to properly order the dates according to the BC boolean column?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `bc=true desc, bc=false asc` is working good. I'll check again when I have my computer and update my answer later.

Maybe my solutions is just a trick or a cheat. This is not a legal way. You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY bc DESC, CASE WHEN bc THEN date*(-1) ELSE date END ASC;
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY bc DESC, CASE WHEN bc THEN abs(date) ELSE date END ASC;
```

Hopefully my answer will satisfy you.

Comment: neat solution, especially given the time to responce

Comment: Are you multiplying the whole date column by  -1 ? I am trying for something like pseudocode : `SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY date IF bc=true THEN desc ELSE asc;` but I keep getting syntax errors, no matter what I try

Comment: btw, it works, I just think that is strange to multiply everything with -1. What if I had 20.000 rows? I am just trying to syntax something purely based on order. But I keep getting errors. I tried nested select, union...Nothing works. This is killing me

Comment: Check my answer if you like. The difference with my solution is that I dont use `*(-1)`. I am no expert to tell if any of the solutions, is better or worst, but I am suggesting another solution. Thanks

Comment: So sorry, I'm out of my computer since yesterday. For your answer, no it is not multiply with (-1) for all data, only the data with bc = true, I've already put it in `CASE WHEN` phase. Or you can replace `date*(-1)` with `abs(date)` as suggestion of @VaoTsun in the answer below. 
From my experience, PostgreSQL do not have condition in `Ordering`, you must pre-process the data first then sort it by ASC or DESC as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [absolute value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html):

```
t=# with c(d) as (values(-51),(50))
select * from c order by abs(d);
  d
-----
  50
 -51
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Ah, very smart soluton, but, lets say I have `-5000102` and `5000102` and do `SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY abs(date), bc desc;`, I get `-5000102 5000102 -5000103 5000103`, so again, no. If the table had those exact fixed values, then yes, but the table could have any value

Comment: @codebot: I think he want to show another way to combine with my answer above. From that the query will be:
`SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY bc DESC, CASE WHEN bc THEN abs(date) ELSE date END ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple union could solve it too.

I tested it on Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96ed2/1/0

It seems to work:

```
( SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE bc=true 
ORDER BY date DESC) 

UNION ALL 
( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE bc=false ORDER BY date)
ORDER BY bc DESC, date
```

The data set I used:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,  
  name VARCHAR (50),
  date INTEGER,
  bc BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date, bc) VALUES (1,'one',-6000102, true);
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date, bc) VALUES (2,'two',-3000202, true);
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date, bc) VALUES (3,'three',-5000103, true);
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date, bc) VALUES (4,'four',19000109, false);
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date, bc) VALUES (5,'five',15000105, false);
```

You should know if `UNION ALL` or `UNION` is the better choice.
( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that if you add another date like `-5000102` they will not order properly. Plus, the union does not guarantee the proper order of both results, the comments in the other question are right. So, check my answer if you like, I came up with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

After testing around and trying different syntax combination, I came up with this, based on [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/468E67AE.6090704%40ipcb.net)

```
select * from test
 order by
 case when bc = true then bc end asc ,
 case when bc = true then date end desc,
 case when bc = false then date end asc,
 case when bc = false then bc end desc;
```

That successfully outputs

```
-5000102
-5000103
-5000103
5000102
5000103
5000301
5000302
15000102
15000103
```

So, dates in the yyyy-mm-dd format, from BC to AD, from older to new.

Comment: Yes, it's work. But I have some worried, because with this case, it will check for 4 conditions and then sort 4 times. I don't think it will be good if the data is larges. BTW, you can try it.
Besides, we can talk more about this case, with `Case` phase, if you don't define the `else` phase, it will be `null` and happily the default of `ASC` is `nulls last`, and vice versa for `DESC`. 
You can check more about `Query Order` here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-order.html