# two different select into the same temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, database-design

In PostgreSQL, I want to do two different `select` with different criteria. Then I want the results of each one to get inserted in the same temp table, without any change of their ordering.

How can I do this? I came up with this

```
create temp table mytable as
select * from test where bc=true order by date desc;
select * into mytable from test where bc=false order by date asc;
select * from mytable;
```

But I get `ERROR:  relation "mytable" already exists`

I want to get for example

```
"one" , -600
"two", -500
```

from the first select and then

```
"three", 1200
"four", 1300
```

from the second table and then `mytable` would have

```
"one" , -600
"two", -500
"three", 1200
"four", 1300
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming that both Select statements are so simple you could try to combine both in one with OR keyword.

Comment: @Tristus How can I do this? Basically,its not that simple, I am trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478216/ascending-or-descending-order-according-to-boolean-column) by getting the results separately and then combining them before showing them

Comment: Please look at the answer I wrote in your other question, I should solve both problems, if not please let me know.

Comment: UNION [ALL] can be used to combine multiple queries.

Comment: You have to use `order by` when selecting from `mytable` if you want to preserve "ordering". Rows in a table are not sorted in any way. The **only** way to get a sorted order you can rely on is to use `order by`

Comment: You shouldn't care about the order of rows in the temp table (or any table, for that matter).  You enforce the order in your query when you retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

Try `union all`.  Your `into` syntax is reminiscent of SQL Server.  Just do:

```
create temp table mytable as
    select * from test where bc = true union all
    select * from test where bc = false;
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of is that, once inserted into the temp table, there is no guarantee they will be returned into the exact same order if you do a simple "SELECT" without an order-by.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume . . . Your comment is absolutely true, but not only about temporary tables but about *any* tables.  If someone wants data in a particular order, then the outermost `select` requires an `order by`.